# IOS Swift SDWebImage not encoding URL, how do I set an encoder for it?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, encode, sdwebimage

I am using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) for loading images from URL.

Following is my code:

```
    if let imageUrl = URL(string: carouselItem.imagesArray[0]) {
    itemImageView.sd_setImage (with: imageUrl,placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceorder"))
    } else {
        itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceorder")

    }
```

Image is not loading as there is a space in the URL. I don't want to encode every individual URL, I want to set an encoder for the image loader itself so that SDWebImage encodes the URL before downloading image.

How do I set a URL Encoder to SDWebImage?

Answer (score 0):

Since they don't have such a possibility you have a few ways to solve it.

1. Since their methods are declared in the extension of UIImageView you cannot override them ([Swift doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)). But you can do it for a subclass:

```
class ImageVIew: UIImageView {

    override open func sd_setImage(with url: URL?, placeholderImage placeholder: UIImage?, options: SDWebImageOptions = [], completed completedBlock: SDExternalCompletionBlock? = nil) {
        // Apply URL encoding
        super.sd_setImage(with: newURL, placeholderImage placeholder, options: options, completed: completedBlock)
    }

}
```

2. Make a fork, add a public property, push MR to the SDWebImage repo